# Date time is wrong when retrieving timestamp from PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, clojure

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE mydate(id serial primary key, date timestamp);
```

Database is configured to be in UTC timezone:

```
SHOW TIMEZONE;

 TimeZone 
----------
 UTC
(1 row)
```

I inserted a test date to the table and when I select it from the table, I see the following result (which looks to be correct):

```
db=# SELECT date FROM mydate;
         date         
---------------------
 2015-11-01 00:00:00
```

Now when I run the same query in Clojure I get the following result:

```
(q "SELECT date FROM mydate")  
=> [[#inst "2015-10-31T22:00:00.000000000-00:00"]]
```

The result is a java.sql.Timestamp object which looks to be 2 hours behind. If I convert the object to JodaTime and ask the current hour, I get 22 (I should have got 0).

However, if I convert the java.sql.Timestamp object string using toString() method I get the following result:

"2015-11-01 00:00:00.0"

**Why is the java.sql.Timestamp object 2 hours behind and why it looks to be correct when to convert it to string?**

Comment: I believe that `timestamptz` is normally recommended in place of `timestamp`.  Have you looked into this option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd generally recommend running your apps in UTC time and only in the view layer taking care of showing the times in the correct timezone. Try setting the JVM flag `user.timezone` to `UTC` (as in `java -Duser.timezone=UTC ...` and/or in your `project.clj`: `:jvm-opts ["-Duser.timezone=UTC"]`).